# ReactJS changing styles via State breaks CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-frontend

So I've been learning react.

And have been learning about states/props and dynamically changing things. As such I set the states set up on a component as such:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.modifyStyle = this.modifyStyle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      navigation: [
        { route: "/", title: "Home" },
        { route: "/about", title: "About Me" },
        { route: "/portfolio", title: "Portfolio" },
        { route: "/contact", title: "Contact" },
        { route: "/", title: "Services" },
      ],
      styling: "nav",
    };
  }
```

Notice the "Styling" state.

This is used to give the list element style as such:

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <div className="trigram">
      <p>&#x2630;</p>
    </div>
    <ul className={this.state.styling}>
      {this.state.navigation.map((items) => (
        <NavItem route={items.route} title={items.title} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

The css for the "Styling" state is this:

```
   .nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: 1s;
   }
```

Which produces, along with the relevant li styling the following on the webpage:

[![Screenshot of menu][1]][1]

The idea is to use the following function to change the list style to a smaller one on a "Scroll" event:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", this.modifyStyle, true);
  }
  modifyStyle = () => {
    this.setState({
      styling: "nav2",
    });
  };
```

The "nav2" style which is being assigned to the state should be identical to the main menu style but with lowered padding.

```
.nav2 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

The function is called and everything works as intended. The style is changed. Yet for some reason the updated styling breaks completely and is stuck looking like this:

[![screenshot issue][2]][2]

I have no idea why this is happening and it seems no amount of debugging the CSS will resolve the issue.
The Styling will just not play game here.

I expect this is something to do with the way React handles states, but I'm not really sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TIA
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK1dt.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Wh2.png

Comment: When you inspect the DOM in your browser's debugging tools, what is the `<ul>` element's `class`?

Comment: so its the default "nav" to begin with, then on scrolling changes to "nav2"

Comment: Then it sounds like the React code is doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing.  Or am I missing something in the question?  How exactly is React not doing what you expect here?  From the description it sounds like you just have CSS styling issues, entirely unrelated to the code shown or the question asked.

Comment: Yeah, the React code is working, I guess I worded the question a bit incorrectly in all honesty. However, the css styling will not work. at all. It seems no amount of debugging it will actually produce the effect I am looking for. It breaks the list, Are you aware of any CSS nuances that might cause this?

Comment: If the problem is only with styling then you are looking in the wrong place.  None of the JavaScript code is relevant.  Update the question to add a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/328193) that includes the relevant HTML and CSS to demonstrate the problem, as well as a description of the behavior you're expecting from that CSS and why.

Comment: Understood. Appreciate the help. Actually just managed to fix this now. Will update the question as resolved with fix. Apologies for wasting your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a React Question, was CSS.

Issue resolved by generalising the "li" tag css. Not specifying it in regards to a specific class